# Microsoft Search Server express 2010 Not crawling pages with forms authentication

Tags: search, authentication, forms-authentication

I can't configure search server to use forms authentication during crawling. I have created crawl rule and set form credentials there with no errors. But during crawl Search server is still considered as anonymous user.

I've found [hot fix for SP 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934577). Is it required for search server 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net has shown to me its power. Search server after accepting provided credentials performs post to receive authentication cookie. But for some reason his post is recognized as click not on login button, but on totally different  than login code expected.

Moved login block at the top of HTML and it works now.